# Node.js and google or tools java

Tags: java, node.js, or-tools

I have a web project and this project needs to google or-tools java. I need to run java file with node.js but I can't. How can I do this?

Firstly I write

`javac -cp "C:\Users\lisec\OneDrive\Masaüstü\java\lib\jna-platform.jar;C:\Users\lisec\OneDrive\Masaüstü\java\lib\ortools-java-9.7.2996.jar;." BasicExample.java`

then
`java -cp "C:\Users\lisec\OneDrive\Masaüstü\java\lib\jna-platform.jar;C:\Users\lisec\OneDrive\Masaüstü\java\lib\ortools-java-9.7.2996.jar;." BasicExample`
But I got error like this

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
        at com.google.ortools.Loader.<clinit>(Loader.java:34)
        at BasicExample.main(BasicExample.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 2 more
```

When I try something different, it cannot find my BasicExample file even though it is in the directory.

Comment: The failure says that com.sun.jna.Platform (Java Native Access) is not present in the class path. You need to provide it as well, as it not part of the JDK. I assume that the or-tools have other dependencies as well. You need to make sure to provide them as well. Maybe a fat jar would help you